# PHP Array to C# String

Tags: c#, php, arrays

In my application, a resquest is sent to a PHP server from a C# application. The application sends details the author name via POST.
I want the PHP application to query a database and return, ideally, an array of the authors details:

C#

```
        String result = "";
        string url = LINK_TO_SITE;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
            {
                {"Author", Properties.Settings.Default.Author}               

            };
            result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(url, postData));
            MessageBox.Show(result);
```

php

```
    $author=$_POST["author"];   
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, date, code FROM Collab where Members=?");    
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $author);
    $stmt->execute();       
    $stmt->bind_result($name,$date, $code);
```

I can retrive the details fine. Now, how will I put the data into an array that can be sent back to C#?

So basically...How do I get a PHP array to work in C#?

Comment: Try encoding the array using `json_encode`, then using a JSON parser class in #c parse the JSON to an array.

Comment: Could you post an example of what your result string looks like? Im not familiar with php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that it depends how you want to send it.  The easiest way is to use separation character in C# for example ";" and then in php

```
$authors = explode(";", $_POST["author"]);
```

you can also use XML or JSON, preg_match() it's up to you. You can format it before sending.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer and the array is sent by PHP and recieved successfully by my application.

My code:
"String[] jsonObject = JsonReader.Deserialize<String[]>(result);"
However, it says I'm missing JSONReader in C#. I've looked around but I've yet to find a copy of it. can you provide me with a link or an alternative code?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object This code lets you work with JSON like you would in JavaScript at run-time.

Comment: Unfortunately, That doesn't seem to work at all.
It seems I'm missing the supporting libraries for that too. 

The following seem to be missing from my system
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Comment: How would this be done via XML. I've had a look around at that too and I haven't found anything solid.

Comment: Hi, I was able to reslve my issues in the end. Thanks for your support